# Binding or execute control.method in mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Textbox has Clear and GetSpellingErrors methods etc.
Is it possible for me to have something like < TextBox Clear={binding...} />?

I am aware Clear is not an "Dependency" anything.  I'm authoring an usercontrol.  I can add the DependencyProperty, DependencyObject as needed.  I just want to know how to bind a method to the VM.

PS I don't need alternatives for Clear, I know I can set the property to string.empty.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use ICommand and create it like any other DependencyProperty.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CancelCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CancelCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(AddressUserControl), new PropertyMetadata());

    [BindableAttribute(true)]
    public ICommand CancelCommand { get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CancelCommandProperty); } set { SetValue(CancelCommandProperty, value); } }
```

The only problem I still have is I need this to be a read-only binding obviously.
Tried

```
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(...)
```

but there appears to be a bug with ReadOnly DependencyProperty https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540833/onewaytosource-binding-from-a-readonly-dependency-property

Comment: You can add this as an edit to your original question.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were asking for more help.